# Foreman runs puma in wrong environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, puma

I want to run puma with next `Procfile` in `production` environment:

```
web: bundle exec puma
```

Next I run foreman:

```
» RAILS_ENV=production foreman start                            
15:47:57 web.1  | started with pid 99864
15:47:57 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
15:47:57 web.1  | * Version 2.8.2 (ruby 2.1.1-p76), codename: Sir Edmund Percival Hillary
15:47:57 web.1  | * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
15:47:57 web.1  | * Environment: development
15:47:58 web.1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
15:47:58 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

See this `Environment: development` line? Why not `production` here?

But if I check environment with `foreman run` it shows `production`.

```
» RAILS_ENV=production foreman run rails runner 'puts Rails.env'
production
```

Is it `foreman` issue, or `puma` issue or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, as recommended in [Puma issues](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/56) - to use `RACK_ENV` instead of `RAILS_ENV`:

```
» RACK_ENV=production foreman start    
16:04:34 web.1  | started with pid 372
16:04:34 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
16:04:34 web.1  | * Version 2.8.2 (ruby 2.1.1-p76), codename: Sir Edmund Percival Hillary
16:04:34 web.1  | * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
16:04:34 web.1  | * Environment: production
16:04:35 web.1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
16:04:35 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: `RACK_ENV` is not the same as `RAILS_ENV`. `RAILS_ENV` is for your application, and can be `development`, `test`, `production` etc. `RACK_ENV` is, as the name implies, for rack, and can be one of `development`, `deployment` or `none`. So the correct way is `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma start -e deployment`

Comment: could you prove this?

Comment: See https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/575bbcba780d9ba71f173921aa1fcb024890b867/lib/rack/server.rb#L157-L162 . There's a common misunderstanding of what `RACK_ENV` is for.